# ADD columns below the lightning path of dynamic size using AURA

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforce1-app

I am working on the custom kanban view for any object and I want to show the dynamic picklist values on the lightning path And show the records below the each value of the picklist how to achieve that thing please try to sort this problem.

```
  <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
            <div class="slds-path">
                <div class="slds-grid slds-path__track">
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-path__scroller-container">
                        <div class="slds-path__scroller">
                            <div class="slds-path__scroller_inner">
                                <ul class="slds-path__nav" role="listbox" aria-orientation="horizontal">
                                    <aura:iteration items = "{!v.pickListValuesList}" var = "picValues">
                                        <li class="slds-path__item slds-is-current slds-is-active" role="presentation">
                                            <a aria-selected="true" class="slds-path__link" href="javascript:void(0);" id="path-1" role="option">
                                                <span class="slds-path__title">{!picValues}</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </aura:iteration>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <div class="slds-grid slds-path__track">
            <div class="slds-grid slds-path__scroller-container">
                <div class="slds-path__scroller">
                    <div class="slds-path__scroller_inner">
                        <ul class="slds-path__nav" role="listbox" aria-orientation="horizontal">
                            <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                                <aura:iteration items = "{!v.pickListValuesList}" var = "pickValues">
                                    <td data-label="Account Name" style="width: 150px;">
                                         <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!pickValues}">Testing Columns</div>
                                    </td>
                                </aura:iteration>
                            </tr>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: This is out put which I am getting But I want to get each data column of size of the path of values]

Comment: Anil, adding your Javascript code would make it more likely to get an answer. But frankly - the HTML looks a bit dodgy: There are no cells inside thead. div tags are not allowed directly [below tr tags](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-tr-element) or [tbody tags](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-tbody-element). There are slds-grid inside slds-grid, but no grid columns. And what has all this to do with salesforce1-app?

Comment: For the kanban view

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I put the below columns in the proper format of the above path